# Collision detection and nearing in R

Tags: r, collision-detection

I have `x` and `y` values for points (on a grid with discrete steps). I want to find those points that are in the same position or within a certain range from another point. I tried with the functions `match()`, `duplicated()`, `which()`, `for` loops, and `if` cases of different kinds and somehow got stuck.

As an example:

```
x <- c(23, 45, 98, 23, 12) 
y <- c(15, 90, 10, 15, 70)
```

[1] and [4] would 'collide' in this case.

```
x <- c(24, 45, 98, 23, 12)
y <- c(14, 90, 10, 15, 70) 
range<-1
```

[1] and [4] would again 'collide' in this case.

Either index or values of the points will do, however I will need one information per collision.

Comment: Try looking at `dist(cbind(x,y), "manhattan")` to see the distances between sets of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is brute force but should work well as long and `x` and `y` are not massive.

```
x <- c(24, 45, 98, 23, 12)
y <- c(14, 90, 10, 15, 70)
range <- 2

temp = as.matrix(dist(cbind(x, y)))
diag(temp) = Inf
unique(t(apply(which(temp < range, arr.ind = TRUE), 1, sort)))
#  [,1] [,2]
#4    1    4
```